# Trying to get file name with the largest size with extension "java"

Tags: java, file

I am using `Files.walk` to list all files from a directory, including all levels of sub-directories with a filter for files that end with "java".

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> files = findFiles(Paths.get("C:\\project"),"java");
    files.forEach(System.out::println);

public static List<String> findFiles(Path path, String extension) throws IOException {
    List<String> result;
    try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(path)) {
        result = walk.filter(p -> !Files.isDirectory(p))
                     .map(p -> p.toString().toLowerCase())
                     .filter(f -> f.endsWith(extension))
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now I want that string list of files to another method to find a file name with the largest size.

I have no idea how to do it and maybe it was a bad idea to put it in a string list.
So I am asking for help or maybe different approach to this problem.

Comment: A Java source code file, i.e. a file that has `.java` extension usually has the same name as the class that it defines. So are you looking for the longest class name? For example if one file is `A.java` and another file is `Xyz.java` then you want `Xyz`. Is that correct?

Comment: No, sorry i didn't put in i a title. I want biggest file size. Something like:  biggest file: A.java 1.23 mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```java
public static void main( final String... args ) throws IOException 
{
  final var file = findLargestFile( Paths.get( "C:\\project" ),"java" );
  System.out.println( file.getAbsolutePath() );
}

public static final File findLargestFile( final Path path, final String extension ) throws IOException 
{
  try( final var walk = Files.walk( path ) ) 
  {
    return walk.filter( p -> !Files.isDirectory( p ) )
      .map( Path::toFile ) 
      .filter( f -> f.getName().toLowerCase( ROOT ).endsWith( extension ) )
      .max( comparingLong( File::length ) )
      .orElse( null );
  }
}
```

`findLargestFile()` eliminates the files that does not have the right extension, then it gets the largest of the remaining files and returns that, or `null` if the source folder was empty.

If you want to get back an instance of `Path`, it may look like this:

```java
public static final Path findLargestPath( final Path path, final String extension ) throws IOException 
{
  final ToLongFunction<Path> size = p ->
  {
     var result = 0L;
     try
     {
       result = Files.size( p );
     }
     catch( final IOException ignored ) {}
     return result;
  }; 

  final Predicate<Path> validExtension = p -> p.getName( p.getNameCount() - 1 )
    .toString()
    .toLowerCase( ROOT )
    .endsWith( extension );

  try( final var walk = Files.walk( path ) ) 
  {
    return walk.filter( p -> !Files.isDirectory( p ) )
      .filter( validExtension )
      .max( comparingLong( size ) )
      .orElse( null );
  }
}
```

Instead of swallowing the `IOException`, you can wrap it into an `UncheckedIOException` and throw that.

Comment: But when i use `.filter( p -> p.getName()` it expect an argument and should I always specify locale when I call `.toLowerCase( ROOT )` or can it be only `.toLowerCase()`  ?

Comment: @Rostnik5522 – `File::getName` does not take an argument, and yes, to ensure that the behaviour of `String::toLowerCase`/`String::toUpperCase` does not depend on the Locale configured with the operating system, you should always specify the Locale you expect. But `Files::walk` returns a `Stream<Path>` not `Stream<File>`, I corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

In below code, method `findFiles` traverses the directory tree, starting at *dir* and filters in regular files whose filename extension is `.java`

It then sorts the files by their size from largest to smallest.

It then collects the files to a `LinkedHashMap` where the [map] key is the path to the file and the [map] value is the size of the file. `LinkedHashMap` maintains the order in which entries are added to it. Since the entries are first sorted before adding them to the `LinkedHashMap`, the first entry is the file with the largest size.

Note that `LinkedHashMap` implements [interface] `SequencedMap` – which was added in Java 21. `SequencedMap` declares method `firstEntry()` that returns the first entry which is the file with the largest size.

Finally, the method prints out the name and size of the largest file.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SequencedMap;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Greatest {

    private static void findFiles(Path dir, String ext) throws IOException {

        // Map key is path to the file.
        Function<Path, Path> keyMapper = path -> path;

        // Map value is file size.
        Function<Path, Long> valueMapper = path -> {
            try {
                return Files.size(path);
            }
            catch (IOException xIo) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(xIo);
            }
        };

        // If two files have the same path (shouldn't occur), return the size
        // of the first file.
        BinaryOperator<Long> mergeFunction = (s1, s2) -> s1;

        // Collect the stream elements into a 'LinkedHashMap'
        Supplier<Map<Path, Long>> mapFactory = () -> new LinkedHashMap<Path, Long>();

        try (Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(dir)) {
            System.out.println(((SequencedMap<Path, Long>) files.filter(p -> Files.isRegularFile(p)  &&
                                                                        p.getFileName().toString().endsWith(ext))
                 .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Path p) -> {
                     try {
                        return Files.size(p);
                    }
                    catch (IOException x) {
                        throw new UncheckedIOException(x);
                    }
                 }).reversed())
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(keyMapper,
                                           valueMapper,
                                           mergeFunction,
                                           mapFactory))).firstEntry());
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path dir;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            dir = Paths.get(args[0]);
        }
        else {
            dir = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        }
        String ext;
        if (args.length > 1) {
            ext = args[1];
        }
        else {
            ext = ".java";
        }
        try {
            findFiles(dir, ext);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want that string list of files to another method to find a file name with the largest size. ..."*

There is a probability that more than one file will be the same size.

Utilize the *[Collectors#groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Collector))* method, with a *[TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html)*, to return only the maximum values.

```java
List<String> findFiles(Path path, String extension) throws IOException {
    List<String> result;
    try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(path)) {
        result
            = walk.filter(p -> !Files.isDirectory(p) && p.toString().endsWith(extension))
                  .collect(
                      Collectors.groupingBy(
                          x -> x.toFile().length(),
                          TreeMap::new,
                          Collectors.mapping(Path::toString, Collectors.toList())
                      ))
                  .lastEntry()
                  .getValue();
    }
    return result;
}
```

As an example, I have a directory with three files, *"a.txt"*, *"ab.txt"*, and *"abc.txt"*.
The sizes are 2, 3, and 4 bytes, respectively.
And, a sub-directory, with two files, *"b.txt"*, and *"bc.txt"*, with sizes 3, and 4, bytes.

Output

```
files/abc.txt
files/more/bc.txt
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question - which was clarified in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77501666/trying-to-get-file-name-with-the-largest-size-with-extension-java#comment136631564_77501666): _I want biggest file size_

Comment: @Abra, _"... I want that string list of files to another method to find a largest file name. ..."_.  They've edited the question since then.  I'll fix it, thanks.